# Azure Data Factory - Read binary byte content

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have multiple binary files in azure blob storage that I need to read and parse content. Problem is that it not a csv file but a binary file with dynamic content. I have c# code to read the file and parse content into class but have no idea how to integrate that in ADF

Comment: ADF can only *copy* binary content (to a binary destination). You won't be able to parse it. You'll need to take a different approach.

Comment: If you used ADF to get the binary file into the Blob storage from some other source, then you can have a blob storage trigger Azure function that can work on each file to parse it. Since you already have c# code for parsing that would be easiest. Btw, after parsing what you intend to do?

Comment: Another alternative is to use `custom activity` in ADF - see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity)

Comment: Challenge of using Azure function is the 5 min timeout. My files are pretty huge and might take more than 5 min for one file to be processed

Answer (score 1):

As you already have the c# code to convert the byte to csv. By considering all the challenges related to 5 in timeout and delay in processing. I would recommend to try the following.

For this you need to expose your C# code as an API and it should be triggered upon an api call.

As soon as the binary files get uploaded to blob, leverage Blob Event Trigger and route the message to your custom api trigger. Which should get the binary file from blob then parse (take own time) then store it back in blob again. If you are able to do this then you can access the parsed file from ADF instead of binary file.